# UIAutomation zooming in on an image

Tags: javascript, ios-simulator

I am writing a script to test an app on iPhone. I want to zoom in on the image.

I tried doing pinchOpenFromToForDuration({x:80, y:150}, {x:30, y:150}, 2) but i keep getting an error:

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'window.scrollViews()[0].images()[0].pinchOpenFromToForDuration({x:80, y:150}, {x:30, y:150}, 2)')

If I hold down the Options key in the iOS simulator and try to zoom in on the image I am able to do it.

The image has these coordinates: rect{{-0, 115},{320, 200}}.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to zoom in on the image?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to call `pinchOpenFromToForDuration` on the image element itself. Pinch gesture methods are only available on the `UIATarget`, so you'd need to say it this way:

```
target.pinchOpenFromToForDuration({x:80, y:150}, {x:30, y:150}, 2);
```

I wish that the individual `UIAElement` objects had a pinch method on them as well, but this is the best we've got at the moment.